# Carregar URL em tag htmlText

Tags: java, actionscript-3, adobe-flex

Preciso carregar uma url dentro desta tag:

```
<mx:HBox id="horizontalBoxInfo" width="100%" >
                <mx:TextArea id="textAreaInfo" 
                             width="100%"
                             height="200"
                             editable="false"
                             horizontalScrollPolicy="off"
                             click="abrirPop(event)"
                             verticalScrollPolicy="auto">
                    <mx:htmlText>
                        <![CDATA[http://mvi.ordersetsmanager.com/evidenceviewer/#/849E3727CA6C3026E05352E3610AEE96/849E3727CA7E3026E05352E3610AEE96%22]]>
                    </mx:htmlText>

                </mx:TextArea>

            </mx:HBox>
```

Contudo, estou recendo o erro:

> Aviso:Falha ao carregar o arquivo de diretivas de
>   http://mvi.ordersetsmanager.com/crossdomain.xml